# Not able to use movtoElement in searchFactory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java-8, webdriver

I am new to selenium and trying to use `moveToElement` in `searchFactory` when executing the code:

```
public class cls1 {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(cls1.class.getName());

    @FindBy(xpath = "")
    WebElement SubMenu;

    public cls1(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void SubMenu(String subMenu) {

        Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);
        action1.moveToElement(SubMenu).build().perform();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Could not find webelement key
```

I am using **Selenium 3.4.0**, **Java 1.8.0_152** on **Windows 10**, could somebody help me with this issue, please?

Comment: At which line are you seeing `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Could not find webelement key`?

Comment: Are you using geckodriver? I have a similar issue with geckodriver but not in Chrome. Could you test it with different browsers?

Comment: Getting error at action1.moveToElement(FlightsSubMenu).build().perform();

Comment: Hi j.barrio, Yes, this problem is occurring with gecko driver only,  works fine with IE, Have to manage to find any solution for Chrome ?

Comment: what is your firefox version? is it supported by geckodriver?